# Which function grows faster: e^n or (log n) factorial?

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function, factorial

How would I solve:

```
e^n / (log n)!
```

where the limit n→infinity

I know that `n!` grows faster than `e^n`.

I think that `(log n)!` would grow faster than `e^n` because the value of `log n` would eventually be close to the value of n that I mentioned above, if that makes sense. Is my reasoning correct? What would be the bounds for a function like `(log n)!`?

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning, because you refer to a "value of n that I mentioned above" but you don't mention any value of n. Also, I believe that e^n grows much faster than (log n)! so I think your conclusion is invalid. I have written a proof as an answer.

Comment: I think $e^{n}$ grows faster by Stirling's formula for $(\log n)!$.

Comment: Since $\log n$ is not an integer, it could be useful to clarify what you mean by $(\log n)!$. It's possible that you would be satisfied something like $\lfloor \log n\rfloor!$ (where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could let $m = \log n,$ that is, $n = e^m,$ so that
$m \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty,$ and therefore

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^n}{(\log n)!} = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{e^{e^m}}{m!}.
$$

Let $f(m) = e^{e^m}/m!.$ Then
$$
\frac{f(m+1)}{f(m)} = \frac{e^{e^{m+1}}/(m+1)!}{e^{e^m}/m!}
= \frac{e^{(e-1)e^m}}{m+1}.
$$

Can you figure it out from here?

Answer (score 2):

Taking logs of both terms: $\mathrm{log}(e^n) = n$ and $\mathrm{log}((\mathrm{log}\ n)!) = (\mathrm{log}\ n)(\mathrm{log}\mathrm{log}\ n) - \mathrm{log}\ n + O(\mathrm{log}\mathrm{log}\ n)$. (Using Stirling's approximation $\mathrm{log}\ k! = k \mathrm{log}\ k - k + O(\mathrm{log}\ k)$).

For $n>3$, $\mathrm{log}\mathrm{log}\ n < \mathrm{log}\ n$, so $\mathrm{log}((\mathrm{log}\ n)!) < 2 (\mathrm{log}\ n)^2$ (for large enough $n$).

All powers of $\mathrm{log}\ n$ are o($n$), so $\log(e^n)$ grows faster than $\mathrm{log}((\mathrm{log}\ n)!)$. And so $e^n$ also grows faster than $(\mathrm{log}\ n)!$

Answer (score 1):

let's calculate the derivative for them.

```
(e^n)' = e^n = a
(log(n))' = 1/(n*ln(2)) = b
```

If **n** increases, then **a** increases and **b** decreases. So, e^n grows faster.

Comment: You've misread the question; the second function is (log *n*)!, meaning, the factorial of the logarithm of *n*. (Note: the factorial is normally defined for integers, but any monotone-increasing extension of it to the reals should be adequate for the question. The usual such extension is just the Gamma function shifted by one.)

Comment: haha thanks for correcting me

Comment: @ruakh Or you could interpret it as (ceil lg n)! which is more likely if these come up in the calculation of a complexity of an algorithm, but it doesn't really make much difference.